# Watir getting started error

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I was trying to begin one project of Watir, to do so i create one file (test.rb)

```
require 'watir'

browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto 'google.com'
browser.text_field(title: 'Search').set 'Hello World!'
browser.button(type: 'submit').click

puts browser.title
# => 'Hello World! - Google Search'
browser.closeenter code here
```

But when i run (ruby teste.rb), it gives me one error

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- watir/loader
 (LoadError)
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/commonwatir-4.0.0/lib/watir.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
        from teste.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

I already install watir (gem install watir).
Can someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `bundle update`. You should not be seeing `commonwatir` gem dependency with Watir 6.x

Comment: Hi again @titusfortner
I create a gemfile (i doesn't have one), but when I run bundle update still gives me the same error.

Here is my gemfile.
`source 'https://rubygems.org' do
  gem 'watir'
  gem 'commonwatir'
end`

By the way i'm using macosx.

Comment: Remove commonwatir, it is also deprecated as of Watir 6

Answer (score -1):

Try with `require "watir-webdriver"`

Comment: Watir WebDriver is deprecated, please don't use.

Comment: `watir-webdriver` is deprecated. It notifies you when you run it with this